# How to delete parts of a file in python?

Tags: python, file, text-processing

I have a file named a.txt which looks like this:

> I'm the first line
>   I'm the second line.
>   There may be more lines here.
>
> I'm below an empty line.
>   I'm a line.
>   More lines here.

Now, I want to remove the contents above the empty line(including the empty line itself).
How could I do this in a Pythonic way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you can't delete stuff from the beginning of a file, so you will have to write to a new file.

I think the pythonic way looks like this:

```
# get a iterator over the lines in the file:
with open("input.txt", 'rt') as lines:
    # while the line is not empty drop it
    for line in lines:
        if not line.strip():
            break

    # now lines is at the point after the first paragraph
    # so write out everything from here
    with open("output.txt", 'wt') as out:
        out.writelines(lines)
```

Here are some simpler versions of this, without `with` for older Python versions:

```
lines = open("input.txt", 'rt')
for line in lines:
    if not line.strip():
        break
open("output.txt", 'wt').writelines(lines)
```

and a very straight forward version that simply splits the file at the empty line:

```
# first, read everything from the old file
text = open("input.txt", 'rt').read()

# split it at the first empty line ("\n\n")
first, rest = text.split('\n\n',1)

# make a new file and write the rest
open("output.txt", 'wt').write(rest)
```

Note that this can be pretty fragile, for example windows often uses `\r\n` as a single linebreak, so a empty line would be `\r\n\r\n` instead. But often you know the format of the file uses one kind of linebreaks only, so this could be fine.

Comment: You can use [os.linesep](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.linesep) instead of '\n', it stores the correct line separator for the current platform.

Comment: @ikostia: That's stupid. The file you're processing can have different line breaks than the one your OS is using by default.

Answer (score 2):

Naive approach by iterating over the lines in the file one by one top to bottom:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open("4692065.txt", 'r') as src, open("4692065.cut.txt", "w") as dest:
    keep = False
    for line in src:
        if keep: dest.write(line)
        if line.strip() == '': keep = True
```

Comment: Corrected to keep lines below the empty line.

Answer (score 1):

The [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput) module (from the standard library) is convenient for this kind of thing. It sets things up so you can act as though your are editing the file "in-place":

```
import fileinput
import sys

fileobj=iter(fileinput.input(['a.txt'], inplace=True))
# iterate through the file until you find an empty line.
for line in fileobj:
    if not line.strip():
        break
# Iterators (like `fileobj`) pick up where they left off. 
# Starting a new for-loop saves you one `if` statement and boolean variable.
for line in fileobj:
    sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Any idea how big the file is going to be?

You could read the file into memory:

```
f = open('your_file', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
```

which will read the file line by line and store those lines in a list (lines).

Then, close the file and reopen with 'w':

```
f.close()
f = open('your_file', 'w')
for line in lines:
    if your_if_here:
        f.write(line)
```

This will overwrite the current file. Then you can pick and choose which lines from the list you want to write back in. Probably not a very good idea if the file gets to large though, since the entire file has to reside in memory. But, it doesn't require that you create a second file to dump your output.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import dropwhile, islice

def content_after_emptyline(file_object):
    return islice(dropwhile(lambda line: line.strip(), file_object), 1, None)

with open("filename") as f:
    for line in content_after_emptyline(f):
        print line,
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a little something like this:

```
with open('a.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

blank_line = lines.index('\n')
lines = lines[blank_line+1:] #\n is the index of the blank line

with open('a.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

and that makes the job much simpler.