# Truncate head of file in Python

Tags: python, file, python-2.7

How to truncate x bytes of the head file ? I have a log which has 5 GB and I want to cut first 3 GB ( remove old information) .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete parts of a file in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4692065/how-to-delete-parts-of-a-file-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `seek` method:

```
fname = 'bigfile.log'
fid = open(fname, "rb")
fid.seek(3 * (2 ** 30) , 0) # go to the ~(3*10^9)th Byte, with respect to the start
Buffer = fid.read(2 * (2 ** 30))
```

Click [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) for more information.

Comment: Is it efficient to load 2 GB to RAM?

Comment: I think it is not efficient. The intention was to demonstrate how to access a specific byte in the file. If it was up to me , I would read the file using a loop.